# When running turtle the window stops responding and the jupyter kernel dies

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

im using jupyter notebook for school, just for some basic math.

im trying to run:

```
from turtle import *

for side in range(4):
  forward(50)
  left(90)
```

it draws it, but when its done the windows that opens up stops responding and jupyter says its kernel died

i have tried running it in Mu editor, it does not crash there.

is this a usual problem or?
i am 100% new to coding so assume i know nothing
thanks :)

i have no idea what to try